# How to exclude an import on client side

Tags: javascript, go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm using [protoc-gen-validate](https://github.com/envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate), which is a code generator plugin for validating protobufs on the serverside. The server is written in Go, but client side, however, is in Javascript. The issue i'm having is that the `protoc-gen-validate` library seems to be included in the built output when using [ts-protoc-gen](https://github.com/improbable-eng/ts-protoc-gen), which is an unsupported language for `protoc-gen-validate`. As a result, a `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error occurs when use the generated javascript code, failing here :
[image: validation error]

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../../validate/validate_pb.js'
Require stack:
- /home/amadeus/HarmonyProject/harmony-grpc-test/gen/core/v1/core_pb.js
- /home/amadeus/HarmonyProject/harmony-grpc-test/index.js
```

I would like to know, how does one exclude this import from the generated code automatically? In addition, it would be nice if the solution kept the proto files immutable, as they are in a git submodule.

Comment: [Don't pate images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1):

Messy hack to fix this, looking for more elegant ways to make this work:

```sh
IN_DIR="./protocol"
PROTOCOL_BUILD_TMP="./protocol-build-tmp"

mkdir -p $PROTOCOL_BUILD_TMP
cp -r $IN_DIR $PROTOCOL_BUILD_TMP

for dir in $(find "${PROTOCOL_BUILD_TMP}" -name '*.proto' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 dirname | sort | uniq); do
  sed -i -E "s/ \[ \(validate.rules(.*)\];/;/g" $(find "${dir}" -name '*.proto')
  sed -i -E "/validate.proto/d" $(find "${dir}" -name '*.proto')
done
rm -r $PROTOCOL_BUILD_TMP
```

Comment: @blueskript did you find any solution to this? I am currently adding an empty validate_pb.js file next to my *_pb.js generated files.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a messy hack but it works.

Create a `validate_pb.js` file along with the generated files and paste the following code in it.

```
var jspb = require('google-protobuf');
var goog = jspb;
var global = (function() {
    if (this) { return this; }
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') { return window; }
    if (typeof global !== 'undefined') { return global; }
    if (typeof self !== 'undefined') { return self; }
    return Function('return this')();
}.call(null));

goog.exportSymbol('proto.tagger', null, global);
```

This solved the issue for me.